# I cannot find the data source for a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

A pivot table source data looks like this:

'\00Work\07 Product\20220-12-11A\Orig[P11 Nov20 MMR_local.xlsx]Pasted values'!$A:$AL

But I cannot find a worksheet named "Pasted values". Am I overlooking something?
I am assuming it is a table name, a named ranged, or a worksheet name.

I have unhidden all worksheets including the very hidden.
What does Pasted values mean, I cannot find any named ranges as well.

Kindly help.

Comment: Since you are asking, you are probably trying to break into someone's secrets. *Pasted Values* should be a worksheet, as you suspect. But I wonder if the term *Orig* may point to a previous version of the workbook. I'm not conversant with methods of hiding a worksheet but it seems to me that Excel's versioning may offer an opportunity. One might just make a change, save, change back and save again to create a *Previous version*. Question is how to access it. In fact, I don't even know what would happen to a pivot table whose source isn't accessible. So, I'll watch this thread :-)

Answer (score 0):

`\00Work\07 Product\20220-12-11A\Orig[P11 Nov20 MMR_local.xlsx]Pasted values'!$A:$AL`

This is referring to:
Range: `$A:$AL`
Sheet: `Pasted values`
File name: `P11 Nov20 MMR_local.xlsx`
Network location: `\00Work\07 Product\20220-12-11A\`

So the table refers to data from a different file.

Not sure what `Orig` means. If it's part of the Network path I would expect another `\` behind that word.